# Need a script using Bean Shell in Jmeter to read response from one sampler and to call different samplers based on condition/s?

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I need to execute a http POST request then based on response I want to execute two different http requests. Which request to execute next, will be decided based on response objects from previous response. I need a Bean shell script which will do this job (or any alternative solution).
Note:
I have already extracted values from response using Regular Expression Extractor, but I am stuck how to write logic in bean shell which will decide which request to execute next.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use BeanShell, you can solve the issue using [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller).

Keep your Test Plan as follows:

```
Test Plan
....Thread Group
........HTTP Request - 1
............Reg Ex Extractor // to retrieve value and store it in "myVar"
........If Contoller //write condition to match first Http Request (A)
............HTTP Request A
........If Controller //write condition to match second request (B) condition
............HTTP Request B
```

So, If controller child's (HTTP requests) only gets executed if the condition returns `TRUE`

Examples:

```
"${myVar}" == "\${myVar}"
```

Or

```
"${myVar}" != "\${myVar}"
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, Below is the use case, We need to make a http request providing valid arguments.
Parse the response of the service. This will return JSON object which contains: enrollment_state i.e. (A, B, C, D) and enrollment_key.
After parsing the response, we need to assert if enrollment_state:
For A or B from the above request, then we need to do run the next request i.e ( fetchProvisionData) and pass the enrollment_key in the payload of the request For C & D, We need basically to do request again and note that enrollment_key will not be returned.

Comment: is the comment related to above question? If yes, can you please add the details of the test plan, json response in screenshots?  If not, post a new question with above details.

Comment: Yes, this is related to the same question. for request A below is the json

Comment: For request A below is the json { "carrierSubscriberNetworkId" : "${carrierSubscriberNetworkId}", "hardwareId" : "${hardwareId}" } , in response to this  we will get value of enrollmentState and enrollmentKey.  The JSON object which contains: enrollmentState i.e. (A, B, C, D) and enrollmentKey, I am aware that we can use 4 if controls i.e. for (A, B, C, D) For A or B from the above request, then we need to run the next request i.e ( fetchProvisionData) and pass the enrollmentKey in the payload of the request For C & D

Comment: can you edit the question with these details? It is hard to read. also add your test plan screenshot image